# Convert ng-model Angular to Javascript - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I have a model of the question, answer id. **question.answer7[20]** && **question.answer7[25]**.

How to convert this ng-model back to HTML and Javascript (or jQuery).

```
<md-checkbox ng-model="question.answer7[20]" ng-true-value="'69'">CheckboxA</md-checkbox>
<md-checkbox ng-model="question.answer7[25]" ng-true-value="'24'">CheckboxB</md-checkbox>
```

I have tried to put the **input** name **answer7[20]** and **answer7[25]**. And try console **$('input[name="answer7"]')**, but seem like jQuery not understand and return null;

```
<input name="answer7[20]" type="checkbox" checked value="69">CheckboxA
<input name="answer7[25]" type="checkbox" checked value="24">CheckboxB

console.log($('input[name="answer7"]')); // return null
```

Sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
console.log($('input[name^="answer7"]'));
```

Comment: Thank you. It's work. But is there a way to get checked value as json? Example: ```{20: 69, 25: 24}```

Comment: Can you please upvote and accept this answer first as it works for your original question? :)

Comment: For your second question I would say you need write code when checkbox is checked and then create object the way you want.

Comment: I only can upvote and accept after 5 min. Stackoverflow blocking me upvote and accept in 5min.

Comment: Seem like I must use attribute data for the 2nd value.

Comment: I do understand that not a problem, whenever you can :)